# Unit Testing WEBAPI Controllers

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-web-api, routes

I have a webapi controller that I am trying to unit test.  However I am struggling to resolve the different types of ControllerContext.  Most of the code examples I see are to do with testing MVC controllers and not Web API controllers.

The controller is defined as:

```
public class OrdersController : ApiController
{
```

I have this code which works when I run the application

```
uri = Url.Route("DefaultRoute", new { httproute = true, Id = order.Id});
```

However when I try to run it as a unit test, it fails.  I have debugged it and find that Url is null when running unit tests, whereas if I run the system normally Url is an object of type System.Web.Http.Routing.UrlHelper.

Any idea how I can get Url.Route() to work when running unit tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For units tests in **Web API 2**, the easier option is for you to provide a Mock version the UrlHelper to your controller instance. This examples uses [Moq](https://github.com/Moq/moq4)

```
        var mockUrlHelper = new Mock<UrlHelper>();    
        ordersCtrl.Url = mockUrlHelper.Object;
```

If you're using a later version of web api, you'd have populate the controller in your test with RouteData. This sample is taken from the [asp.net website](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/testing-and-debugging/unit-testing-controllers-in-web-api) :

```
 controller.Configuration = new HttpConfiguration();
 controller.Configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi", 
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });

 controller.RequestContext.RouteData = new HttpRouteData(
    route: new HttpRoute(),
    values: new HttpRouteValueDictionary { { "controller", "products" } });
```